# "I need it to lift 2 tons this time." "I don't know if it *could* do." Why do some people use "do" like this?

Tags: verbs, auxiliary-verbs

Sometimes, instead of saying "could/can" or "would/will" (the two most common I've heard), some people say "could/can do" or "would/will do".

Instead of:

> I don't know if it *can*.

I sometimes (but uncommonly) hear:

> I don't know if it *can* do.

Say them with a mild emphasis on the italicized *can* and you'll be saying it as I hear it.

As this is a little hard to express to someone who has never come across it before, I hope someone who sees this knows what I mean.  Why is that extra "do" sometimes used?

***Additional note:*** Here are three examples that in jwpat7's opinion may be similar to or represent what Daniel δ refers to:

> I have never crossed the Himalayas, though I might have done. - [Christopher Hughes](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%20might%20have%20done%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1969,cd_max:2008&lr=lang_en#q=%22I+might+have+done%22&hl=en&lr=lang_en&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1969,cd_max:2008,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=nbMLT8_-EaKmiQLd0bD8Aw&start=10&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=91f960342228ac50&biw=906&bih=532), 2006
>
> ...when I could get a vote for Mr. Charlesworth, I did do. ... I made no regular canvass, [but] where I could get a vote, I did do. - [Slade testimony](http://books.google.com/books?id=SNESAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA275&dq=%22I+did+do%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8ckLT5f6JYeqiQLQ8_GcBA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20did%20do%22&f=false), 13487-8, 1860
>
> "... When needed I will turn myself in too. And if I can do, you can do too!" - [Oblivion in Progress](http://books.google.com/books?id=RPAHVyyduB0C&pg=PA67&dq=%22and+if+I+can+do+you+can+do+too%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6YYMT6nKFIP-iQK24bzzAw&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22and%20if%20I%20can%20do%20you%20can%20do%20too%22&f=false), 2011, pp. 67-68

Comment: "Can do, can do, this guy says the horse can do."

Comment: This usage is regional.

Comment: The song I quoted three comments above, from *Guys and Dolls,* was written by Frank Loesser, a New Yorker. I'm fairly sure it's also regional in the U.S. I know I've heard it here.

Comment: Can you give us some more detail to go on?  *Who* says it?  In what context?

Comment: @Pitarou, see additional note in question

Comment: If I get married in America, I'll say "I".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this is a primarily UK usage. The difference comes in how American and British english speakers handle **verb phrase ellipsis**, a construction in which a verb phrase is left out because it's implied or repeated. Consider this example (taken from [this blog post](http://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/09/pro-predicate-do-and-verb-phrase.html), which contains an excellent discussion of the issue):

> A: I ate all the chocolate, even though I shouldn't have [eaten all the chocolate].

In such situations, American speakers tend to simply delete the elided phrase:

> I ate all the chocolate, even though I shouldn't have.

But British speakers tend to replace the elided phrase with the **[pro-verb](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/GlossaryOfLinguisticTerms/WhatIsAProVerb.htm)** *do*: (A pro-verb is the verbal counterpart of a pronoun, also called a **propredicate**. They are both part of the general category of pro-forms, or words that take the place of a specific part of speech.)

> I ate all the chocolate, even though I shouldn't have **done**. (*BrE*)

Note that American English also has a pro-verb construction, but they use *do so* instead of *do*:

> I ate all the chocolate, even though I shouldn't have **done so**.

According to [this source](http://books.google.com/books?id=WXDpc4MOBo4C&lpg=PA351&ots=yTlCWM6N-Y&dq=british%20propredicate%20do&pg=PA351#v=onepage&q&f=false), all three forms are acceptable in British English, while only *do so* and complete deletion are okay in standard American English. (There are a few American dialects that do use pro-verb *do* - see [this article](http://www.jstor.org/sici?sici=0003-1283%28199324%2968:4%3C339:PDITEO%3E2.0.CO;2-T&) for a discussion - but the vast majority do not.)

The phenomenon occurs very freely - with almost any elided verb-phrase that's introduced by an auxiliary. Thus, in British English you'll hear *I might do, I can do, I will do, I could do, I would do*, etc, while the more likely American equivalents would be *I might, I can, I will, I could, I would*.

Returning to your specific example, we can see that it can be expressed in three possible ways, which vary in terms of usage.

> I need it to lift 2 tons this time...
>
> (1) I don't know if it can. (*common in AmE and BrE*)
>
> (2) I don't know if it can do. (*impossible in AmE, common in BrE*)
>
> (3) I don't know if it can do so. (*possible in both AmE and BrE*)

Answer (score 3):

Because "do" is a regular pro-verb in English.

> "Do you think this is right?" "Yes I do".
>
> "Do you want some melon?" "Yes I do".

When there is an auxiliary such as "will" or "can" it is optional, but can still occur.

This probably developed from "do" as an emphatic auxiliary ("I *do* want some"), through its use as a negative and interrogative auxiliary, which eventually became compulsory for most verbs ("Do you know?" replacing earlier "Know you?")

**Edit**: I realise, rereading the question, that you are asking about the doubt implied by the usage. It usually (though not always) has a certain doubt about it, but the meaning is not

> I don't know if it can

but rather

> It can, but there might be a better way to do it.

So it is still asserting the statement, but there is an implied "but" or "if" following.

Comment: I don't know which aspect (pro-verb vs. doubt) interests Dδ, but the tail of the question title and examples I added address the former.