# "I will do" or "I will do that"

Tags: grammaticality, ellipses

I have come across the phrase *I will do* used as a response. Somehow, it seems incomplete. Shouldn't it be *I will do that*?

Comment: Are you sure it was that? It's more likely to be 'will do'.

Comment: This is also an important question to answer. You might have P1: “You  will go and look it up and find out.”  P2: "I will!"

Comment: "Can do, can do, this guy says the horse can do." —Frank Loesser, lyricist for *Guys and Dolls,* born in New York.  See also [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35227/i-need-it-to-lift-2-tons-this-time-i-dont-know-if-it-could-do-why-do-so).

Comment: This is by non-native speakers. It is not a phrase that I have ever heard or read elsewhere. I guess the question is whether the phrase is grammatically correct but wrong as being not used in language, or is it simply wrong grammatically and customarily? And if it is wrong grammatically then why?

Comment: Found my answer.  http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/455771?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101302396503

Comment: I think the confusion might be where the non-native speakers might be putting the stress. I hear them put the stress on "do" which jars the ears or is it that I just have american ears?

Comment: As Will Hunting's answer shows, the phrase is customary in one context, strange in another. The question can be improved by adding more context leading up to the phrase. The question also shows no research effort.

Answer (score 4):

The reply *I will do* is to me less common than the other possibilities *I will* and *I will do so*, but perfectly normal. *I will do that* (in this sense) is even less likely, but still possible.

Answer (score 3):

*I will do* might be a response to *Will you do that?* in which case *I will do that* is a more usual response. However *I will do* could also be a response to the question *Who is good enough for the job?*, in which case it means *I am good enough*.